# What symmertry of $x$ the solution is referring to?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Here is the question and its answer:

> [image]

> [image]

What symmertry of $x$ the solution is referring to?

Comment: The curve, including its variable thickness, is symmetric w.r.t. reflection in the y-axis.

Comment: @TedShifrin The symmetry is about the y axis, i.e. the line x=0. NOT around y=0.

Comment: Agh, mental slip.

Comment: The wire is symmetric about the $y$-axis, i.e., $x=0$, so the center of mass must lie on $x=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I do not see how $x=0$ because the wire is symmetric about the $y$ axis, is not the points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ are on the wire and $x \neq 0$?

Comment: If you take a little chunk of wire of length $\Delta s$ (very, very small) at the point $(x,y)$, there is a symmetrically located chunk at the point $(-x,y)$. The center of mass of those two chunks is a very small chunk at the point $(0,y)$.

Comment: Are you mis-interpreting what Ted Shifrin is saying? It is the center of mass $\bar x = 0$. When Ted says $x = 0$ in his comment, both times, he is giving the *equation* for the $y$-axis, (the first time as he just said, the second time, this is why he says "must lie on" before it). For any mass to the left of the $y$-axis, there is an equal balancing mass the same distance to the right of the $y$-axis, so their combined center of mass is on the $y$-axis. And the $y$-axis is the *line* $x = 0$, so all points lying on it have $0$ as their $x$-coordinate.